# What is difference between running the script as ./script.sh and . ./script.sh

Tags: bash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between launching a script with ./script.sh and . ./script.sh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880735/difference-between-launching-a-script-with-script-sh-and-script-sh)

What is difference between running the script as ./script.sh and . ./script.sh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The built-in command `.` causes the script to be run in the current process rather than in a subprocess. Using `.` allows your script to alter the environment of the current process. For example:

```
$ echo $FOO

$ cat script.sh
#!/bin/bash export FOO="this is foo" 
$ ./script.sh 
$ echo $FOO

$ . ./script.sh 
$ echo $FOO 
this is foo
```

Notice how in the second case, the environment variable FOO was created in the current process.

Here's a link to the bash man page section dealing with the `.` command:

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-g_t_002e-108

Comment: As an example, if variables are defined in the script, after running with ./script.sh they won't be available in the current shell; they will if running with . ./script.sh

Answer (score 4):

The sourced in (`. ./script.sh`) script runs in the same shell. Meaning that if it issues `exit`, your shell exits, if it sets environment variable, your shell is affected, etc. Normally, you want to run scripts in isolated subprocess (`./script.sh`).

Answer (score 1):

`./script.sh` runs the script. A new sub-shell is spawned and the script runs in it. Any changes to the environment made by the script will be local to the sub-shell. Once the subshell exits you won't see the changes made by it in the parent shell.

`. ./script.sh` sources the script that is it is run in the current shell so any environment changes made by the script will remain after the script exits.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what makes it interesting:

```
$ cat script.sh
export HELLO=SIRE
$ ./script.sh
$ set | grep HELLO
$ . ./script.sh
$ set | grep HELLO
HELLO=SIRE
```

As you can see adding a "." makes the script run in the context of the current shell instead of as a separate process, and affects the environment of the current process, and everything else that comes with the current process.

This can be real fun if you do something like:

```
alias go=". /home/x/bin/navigate_to_location"
```

then just do:

```
go sources
go builddir
go games
```

and the current environment gets affected by the "." ;-)

So in short .. "." makes shell worth having :)