# What is the difference of . and ./?

Tags: bash

What is the difference of trigger a script as `.` or as `./`? For example:

```
echo "echo hi" > script.bash
chmod +x script.bash
./script.bash 
# outputs hi
. script.bash 
# outputs hi
```

Comment: Absolutely everything.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Not a very helpful answer, however true it may be.

Comment: @kqr: That's why it's a comment, and not an answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1880735/1030675

Comment: surely this is a question for slashdot?

Comment: @Gusdor can't see why it wouldn't be: It is self contained, technical and related to development. Just because it is short, it is not invalid - it is even better, actually. The problem is that I failed to find the duplicated question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`./` is a shortcut for the current directory, if you call `./script.bash` you simply call the script in the current directory.

`. script.bash` is something different, here `.` is a shortcut to [source a file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_%28command%29), the long version would be `source script.bash`. Sourcing means the script is executed in the current context. E.g. if your script changes the directory, you actually are in that directory after the script has run, which would not be the case if you simply execute your script with `./script.bash`, as then the script has it's own context.

Comment: ah well, then my answer ist completly wrong... :P i delete it.

Answer (score 0):

`./filename` means you are referring to filename in current directory.

`. filename` is a kind of include statement (includes an external file in your current script file, can be used to store functions in an external file and then be able to call them within your script file) I ofen use it for this purpose in my scripts, very handy !

Edit :
Odi has explained it much better ;)